# There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405). Request method 'GET' not supported with spring boot

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I'm trying to create delete function with Spring boot, reactjs and axios.
For first step, I just confirm if delete action is activated by entering URL directly.
But It doesn't work even if I enter URL directly.
I know GET is not supported but I don't know which I should fix.
Please tell me if you know.
[image]

ActionController.java

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.repository.CheckListRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.CheckListService;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("action/")
@RestController
public class ActionController {

    @Autowired
    CheckListRepository clr;

    @Autowired
    CheckListService cls;

    @DeleteMapping(path = "{deleteId}")
    public void deleteAction(@PathVariable Integer deleteId) {

        clr.deletebyListNo(deleteId);

    }

}
```

PS: This is axios code about contents.
Controller

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.entity.CheckList;
import com.example.demo.entity.CheckListForm;
import com.example.demo.repository.CheckListRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.CheckListService;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class CheckListController {

    @Autowired
    private CheckListRepository checkListRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CheckListService cls;

    @GetMapping("list")
    public List<CheckListForm> getList() {

        List<CheckList> checkList = this.checkListRepository.findAll();

        List<CheckListForm> checkListForm = cls.entityToForm(checkList);

        return checkListForm;

    }

}
```

CheckList.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

const CHECKLIST_REST_API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/api/list';

class CheckListService {

    getList() {
        return axios.get(CHECKLIST_REST_API_URL);
    }
}


export default new CheckListService();
```

Comment: Could you add axios call code in the react..?

Comment: Thank you for comment.
I'm just trying to confirm deleteAction method in controller for first step by entering URL directly like "http://localhost:8080/action/1".
So I've not create axios call code about delete. 
I just create show table code in react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could confirm delete action method in control is activated in the following way.
I changed code

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.repository.CheckListRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.CheckListService;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("action/")
@RestController
public class ActionController {

    @Autowired
    CheckListRepository clr;

    @Autowired
    CheckListService cls;

    @DeleteMapping(path = "{deleteId}")
    public void deleteAction(@PathVariable Integer deleteId) {

        clr.deletebyListNo(deleteId);

    }

}
```

to

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.demo.repository.CheckListRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.CheckListService;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("action/")
@RestController
public class ActionController {

    @Autowired
    CheckListRepository clr;

    @Autowired
    CheckListService cls;

    @RequestMapping(path = "{deleteId}")
    public void deleteAction(@PathVariable Integer deleteId) {

        clr.deletebyListNo(deleteId);

    }

}
```